# Convert filter expression to NSPredicate format

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I would like to perform this filter method using NSPredicate, but I'm having trouble converting the syntax.

```
objectsCollection.filter { $0.stringIds.contains(id) }
```

**Sample class**

```
class Object {
    let stringIds: [String]
}

let objectsCollection: [Object]
let id = "The id we want to look for"
objectsCollection.filter { $0.stringIds.contains(id) }
```

**My attempt with NSPredicate**

This is how I thought it would work, but seems like it doesn't.

```
let filter = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN stringIds", id)
objectsCollection.filter(filter)
```

**Error**

```
reason: 'Expected object of type (null) for property 'stringIds' on object of type 'Object', but received: 6011ea4dda6853a3af97376e'
```

Comment: " but seems like it doesn't." what happens?

Comment: Just updated the question with the error I received @Alexander

Comment: In my original code I cast the string as NSPredicate(format: filterString) I just didn’t include that in this question

Comment: I know nothing about realm, but Swift array `filter` method simply doesn't take an NSPredicate. But if this is some other `filter` method that _does_ take an NSPredicate, I would ask, can you use a [_block_](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/1416182-init) predicate here? They are a lot easier to write.

Comment: Can you show an example of a block predicate?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues that need to be addressed.

This

```
let stringIds: [String]
```

is not a realm object and will not be persisted in Realm.

That needs to be a List property and the object type of the list is another Realm object. Realm Lists do not support primitives (very well). Also, don't name your objects the same name as another object.

```
class MyClass: Object {
    let myStringIdList = List<MyStringIdClass>
}
```

and

```
class MyStringIdClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var myId = ""
}
```

to then get all of the MyClass objects that had a certain stringId in their list

```
let results = realm.objects(MyClass.self).filter("ANY myStringIdList.myId == %@", idToFind)
```

The string inside `.filter` can also be an NSPredicate if needed.

You can also use LinkingObjects to navigate back to the MyClass objects as well.

One other thing, when you cast realm objects to an array, they loose their connection to realm and are no longer live updating objects.

Also, Realm objects are lazily loaded meaning that thousands of objects have very little memory impact. Casting them to an array however, loads ALL of that data and can overwhelm the device with a large data set.

Comment: Do I have to put the list of string ids in another class?

Comment: @MichaelJajou Take a look at my answer at the `MyStringIdClass` - the string id's are store in the `MyStringIdClass` class and the MyClass has a list of those.

Comment: So there’s no way to do it just using a regular realm list and not creating another object

Comment: @MichaelJajou *No way* is subjective. You *can* store primitives but they are not queryable and your loose a lot of functionality by doing that. Best Practice is to use a class to store the string.